# Validate Chrome.exe from official website

Tags: certificate, rsa-key-fingerprint, x509certficiate2

How can I verify whether the 'chrome.exe' on my machine was installed from the official Chrome website? Is there a way to detect if someone has created a fraudulent executable, mimicking 'chrome.exe,' and signed using private CA  and added their certificates to my private CA in the certificate store?

I just tried to compare the certificates from official website .

Comment: You could compare the md5checksum of the two executables.